# How to center align widget in Flutter form on web

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am building a flutter project on both app and web. I am having a couple of issues with the login page. First my column widget fills the whole width on Flutter web but I want it to be more central. Secondly I am trying to center align the **Don't have an account? Sign up** button which has found itself aligning to the left. Please may someone assist. Here's my code and a couple of screenshots

[image]

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) =>
                        value!.isEmpty ? 'Email cannot be empty' : null,
                    onSaved: (value) => _email = value!,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) =>
                        value!.isEmpty ? 'Password cannot be empty' : null,
                    onSaved: (value) => _password = value!,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      filled: true,
                      fillColor: Colors.white,
                      labelText: 'Password',
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    ),
                    obscureText: true,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/resetpassword');
                    },
                    child: const Text('Forgot Password?'),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: validateAndSubmit,
                    child: const Text('Login'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.black,
                      onSurface: Colors.black,
                      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Text('Dont have an account?'),
                      TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signup');
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Signup',
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

To center the  'Dont have an account?' text and 'Signup' TextButton,
use mainAxisAlignment in Row.

```
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,//<-- this
                  children: [
                    const Text('Dont have an account?'),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/signup');
                      },
                      child: const Text(
                        'Signup',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

To responsive web and app,
I use this method,

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
     const ResponsiveLayout(), 
  );
}
```

In my ResponsiveLayout `const webScreenSize = 600;`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        if (constraints.maxWidth > webScreenSize) {
          //webscreen
          return widget.webScreenLayout; // <-- send user Web screen
        } else {
          //mobile screen
          return widget.mobileScreenLayout; // <-- send user mobile screen
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Read more about LayoutBuilder -
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html